# How do I programmatically detect presence changes in the messaging menu?

Tags: application-development, messaging-menu, dbus

Is there a way to subscribe to messaging menu events? Specifically, I'm looking for a signal (over DBus?) that is fired when the online presence status changes in the messaging menu

Comment: http://telepathy.freedesktop.org/spec/Connection_Interface_Simple_Presence.html the dbus api you're looking for is here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The messaging menu uses the Telepathy framework and sends the status events to Telepathy's Mission Control.  The webpage that describes Telepathy and how it works is here:

- http://telepathy.freedesktop.org/wiki/

If you use the Telepathy-GLib library you're probably looking for the ["most-available-presence-changed"](http://telepathy.freedesktop.org/doc/telepathy-glib/telepathy-glib-account-manager.html#TpAccountManager-most-available-presence-changed) signal from the TpAccountManager object.